# How to implement TextTheme inside the ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to have a different file for the style of the whole application, and then call the function in the main.dart file.

```
ThemeData appTheme1() {
  const colorBlack = const Color(0xFF4C4B4B);
  const colorWhite = const Color(0xFFDAE0E2);
  const colorGrey = const Color(0xFF7B8788);
  return ThemeData(
    primaryColor: colorBlack,
    accentColor: colorWhite,
    // hintColor: Colors.white,
    // dividerColor: Colors.white,
    buttonColor: colorBlack,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: colorWhite,
    // canvasColor: Colors.black,
    fontFamily: "NanumMyeongjo",
  );
}
```

The question is how can I add the styling of the text inside this ThemeData?
Thanks.

Comment: Is your question really how to implement a **text theme**, when the parameter is called `textTheme` and is of type `TextTheme`? Please get an IDE that can autocomplete parameters for you. Or read the documentation. Preferably both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `textTheme` property: I added an example using your code:

```
ThemeData appTheme1() {
  const colorBlack = const Color(0xFF4C4B4B);
  const colorWhite = const Color(0xFFDAE0E2);
  const colorGrey = const Color(0xFF7B8788);
  return ThemeData(
    primaryColor: colorBlack,
    accentColor: colorWhite,
    // hintColor: Colors.white,
    // dividerColor: Colors.white,
    buttonColor: colorBlack,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: colorWhite,
    // canvasColor: Colors.black,
    fontFamily: "NanumMyeongjo",
    // use the textTheme property
    textTheme: TextTheme().copyWith(
      headline1:  TextStyle(
        // add your styles
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Stylist` package? (https://pub.dev/packages/stylist). It's easier and cleaner apply themes using it.